# Version of msvcrXX.dll that my Python interpereter compiles with

Tags: c++, dll, python-3.x

I have compiled my Python 3.3 application to a `.exe` with `cx_Freeze` and it's only run on my local machine.

On another computer, first it had an issue with a missing DLL, `msvcr100.dll`.
After I installed `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package` on that computer, it doesn't show any errors, but still doesn't work because nothing opened.

I think that I installed wrong version of `Microsoft Visual C++  Redistributable`. How can I find out the version of `msvcrXX.dll` that my Python interpreter compiled with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.3 is compiled with Visual Studio 2010. That uses Msvcr100.dll.

You can view the compiler via `sys.version` or `platform.python_compiler()`:

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import platform
>>> sys.version
'3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]'
>>> platform.python_compiler()
'MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)'
>>> ^Z
```

This is Visual Studio 2010's compiler version:

```
C:\>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]
```

More directly, you can example the DLL imports of the Python DLL directly:

```
C:\>dumpbin /imports c:\windows\system32\python33.dll | findstr /i dll
Dump of file c:\windows\system32\python33.dll
File Type: DLL
    KERNEL32.dll
    USER32.dll
    ADVAPI32.dll
    SHELL32.dll
    MSVCR100.dll
```

Comment: tnx for your answer but I installed 2010 version after and nothing changed.

Comment: That doesn't make the answer incorrect :)  Check that `cx_Freeze` was used correctly.  Unfortunately I've never used it.

Comment: @user2940876 This is the answer to the question that you asked. You need to understand the difference between the answer to your question, and the solution to your problem.